# Changing a lightbox into an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, lightbox

I am trying to rewrite this link so instead of linking to a light box, it makes an ajax call and updates the contents of `<div class = "add-rule>`. Here is the link

```
<div class="add-rule>"<a href = "/saffron_main/add_rule?type=tid&mid=0&cid=1&m-name=valid"  class="lightwindow" params="lightwindow_type=external,lightwindow_height=100,lightwindow_width=300">Add a rule</a></div>
```

I am new to Javascript and Ajax, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you using any framework? Did you already made anything in JS or Ajax?

Comment: You have a syntax mistake - `<div class="add-rule>"` , instad use move the quotation marks inside. `<div class="add-rule">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should look some like this (couldn't check this out but I am not far away)
For more info have a look at [jquery's ajax api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) 
and you might be interested in the [load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

This is my code, let me know if it fits or not

```
<div class="add-rule">
    <span id="addRuleError"></span>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="loadContent()" class="lightwindow"
                         params="lightwindow_type=external,lightwindow_height=100,lightwindow_width=300">Add a rule</a>
</div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadContent()
            {
                $("#addRuleError").text("");
                $.ajax({
                    url:"saffron_main/add_rule",
                    data:{type:"tid", mid:0, cid:1, "m-name": "valid"},
                    success:function(result){$(this).parent().html(result)},
                    error:function(result){$("#addRuleError").html(result.responseText)}
                })
            }

        </script>
```